# How to use Apache2 as a reverse proxy in Ant Media?

Tags: apache-2.2, webrtc

We want to use Apache2 as reverse proxy like Nginx in front of A[nt Media Server](https://github.com/ant-media/Ant-Media-Server/). Even if http/s connections are succesfull, websocket connection cannot be established and we cannot publish webrtc live stream to [Ant Media](https://antmedia.io) Server. What do you recommend to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

here are the instruction for how to use Apache as reverse proxy.

1. Enable the modules:

```
a2enmod proxy proxy_http proxy_wstunnel
```

2. Edit `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ams.conf` file

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName yourdomain.com
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/yourdomain.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/yourchain.crt
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:5080/$1 [P,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*)           http://localhost:5080/$1 [P,L]
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:5080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5080/
</VirtualHost>
```

3. And restart the apache2 service:

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).